# Counting Active Rows within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to count and include active accounts per day over a timeframe (@params determine the time frame window). But the result must specify per day the number of active accounts. My struggle is with this: how to include accounts per day? Is it using dynamic SQL? if so, how?

Requirements: Count and include active accounts for per day:

1. An active account is one that has an start date PRIOR to or equal to the date displayed yet, the endDate is after the same date
2. If an account has an enddate of NULL that means it is active (assuming it has an start date that falls in the range)
   Example: an account with start date of 2020-03-01 and end date of 2020-03-04 would be considered active on
   2020-03-01, 02, 03 and 04. It should be included/counted in those days.
   But not on 2020-02-28 or 2020-03-05.

```
    SELECT 
                A.Date, 
                A.Location, 
                count(*) as ActiveAccs ,
                CountOfAccounts as numOfAccs, 
                ServiceCategory , 
                CountOfAccounts-count(1) as AvailableAccs, 
                
    FROM accLocationStats A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts  B
    ON A.Location=B.Location 
    
    WHERE   b.StartDate is not null --StartDate of Null = they are unwanted accounts
            
            --this is where things go bad. Do I need dynamic SQL? 
            AND ( b.EndDate is NULL)
           
           --Examination window: we want accounts in this time frame . Please remember that I need to count per day, NOT count for the entire period. 
            AND (Date>=@param1 AND Date<=@param2)
    GROUP BY  A.Date,a.Location,CountOfAccounts,ServiceCategory
```

Comment: Provide sample data (scripts would be nice) and expected result would help in great way to answer

Answer (score 0):

I see you have Start- and EndDate on the Accounts table and Date on the accLocationStats table, should the @params only be applied on the Date field? In which case you could probably just use:

```
a.Date BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
```

If the @params need to be applied on the Start- and EndDate fields too you could add one of the following:

```
b.StartDate BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
AND ISNULL(b.EndDate, @param2) BETWEEN @param1 AND @param2
```

Or

```
@param1 BETWEEN b.StartDate AND ISNULL(b.EndDate, @param1)
AND @param2 BETWEEN b.StartDate AND ISNULL(b.EndDate, @param2)
```

Or

```
b.StartDate >= @param1
AND ISNULL(b.EndDate, b.StartDate) <= @param2
```

Dynamic SQL should not be necessary for this and these conditions can just be added in the  where clause.

Comment: not quite. The parameter dates were somewhat of a distraction and I wish I didn't include it. If I run this query, this will just give me the aggregate of the whole period. The struggle was to show the daily counts.

Comment: You might need to consider removing all of the other non-aggregate fields from the select and group by clauses leaving only the Date and fields containing COUNT(*), this might be why you are not seeing the correct numbers per day.

Comment: well I am not getting any numbers. But will try different methods to see if I can get somewhere

Comment: Perhaps add some additional information on the question with data in your tables, the current output you are getting and the expected output. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, having a simple table of dates is invaluable. If you want to end up with one result per day, the only way to guarantee you'll have that is a table that contains each date. I recommend a permanent table called "dates" or something that contains every day for recent history (200 years or so). Then you can select on that and do a subquery on your accounts to see which were active during that date. Here's an example of how I would do it on a customer table that I have similar to your situation.

```
declare @fdate as date = '2020-06-01',@tdate as date = '2020-06-30'

select d.date,(select count(*) from CustMast c where c.installdate >= d.date and c.pulldate <= d.date) activeAccts
from dates d
where d.date between @fdate and @tdate
```